# Screen shift in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, display

I have Ubuntu on my System and at every boot my screen shifts to the right by some amount and therefore I have to press the auto-configure button on my Monitor to shift it back. So I have to do this at every startup and its getting very annoying. How can I fix this problem?